# How to check if php mysqli_fetch_array is empty before while loop

Tags: php

I wanted to make sure there are results before running the while loop but all the methods I am trying seem to remove the first result.

```
$nearbyResult = mysqli_query($con,$sqlNearby);

if(mysqli_fetch_array($nearbyResult) == 0) {
    echo '<p>No results found, <a href="/add.php">Add your property here</a>.</p>';
} else {
    while($rowNearby = mysqli_fetch_array($nearbyResult)) {
    }
}
```

Comment: IF you just just have one loop where you fetch the results, it won't go into the loop if they are no records fetched. There's no need to check if it is empty before the loop.

Comment: `if(mysqli_num_rows($con)){/*Code to execute if rows are returned*/}else{echo "Nothing to show!";}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line will take the first row of your result set and chuck it in the bin:

```
if(mysqli_fetch_array($nearbyResult) == 0) {
```

Change to:

```
if( ! mysqli_num_rows($nearbyResult) ) {
```

And check your freakin function returns:

```
if( ! $nearbyResult = mysqli_query($con,$sqlNearby) ) {
    echo "Mysql error: " . mysqli_error($con);
}
```

Comment: Probably shouldn't do page echoing right in the middle of some data access code, but yes.. check your data returns...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mysql_row_count method to count how many rows are returned in your query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning the results to a variable as part of your if statement.  If mysqli_fetch_array() has no result set to work with it will return false.

```
if($rowNearby = mysqli_fetch_array($nearbyResult)) {
    //There was a result, work with it here
    doStuffWith($rowNearby);
} else {
    //No records in your result set, handle as desired
}
```